# PostProcessInterceptor: How to access HTTP request?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, authentication, java-ee-6, resteasy

I have an interceptor that looks like

```
@Interceptor
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
@SecurityChecked
public class SecurityCheckInterceptor implements PreProcessInterceptor, AcceptedByMethod, PostProcessInterceptor {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityCheckInterceptor.class);

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ServerResponse preProcess(final HttpRequest request, final ResourceMethod method) throws Failure, WebApplicationException {
        final List<String> authToken = request.getHttpHeaders().getRequestHeader(AUTH_TOKEN);

        if (authToken == null || !isValidToken(authToken.get(0))) {
            final ServerResponse serverResponse = new ServerResponse();
            serverResponse.setStatus(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED.getStatusCode());
            return serverResponse;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public boolean accept(final Class declaring, final Method method) {
        // return declaring.isAnnotationPresent(SecurityChecked.class);
        return method.isAnnotationPresent(SecurityChecked.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcess(final ServerResponse response) {
        LOGGER.info("post-processing response " + response.getEntity());
    }

}
```

**What I want ?**
- Every time the response goes back I need to add a new `AUTH_TOKEN` value
- The original `request` has access to request headers and one of the header is of the form

```
signature:user:expires
```

- I need the access to `user` form this `request` header to generate a new time-based token

How can I have access to `request` headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added

```
@Context HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
```

and that gave me access to headers.

My modified Interceptor looks like

```
@Interceptor
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
@SecurityChecked
public class SecurityCheckInterceptor implements PreProcessInterceptor, AcceptedByMethod, PostProcessInterceptor {
    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(":");
    @Context
    HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityCheckInterceptor.class);

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ServerResponse preProcess(final HttpRequest request, final ResourceMethod method) throws Failure, WebApplicationException {
        final List<String> authToken = request.getHttpHeaders().getRequestHeader(AUTH_TOKEN);

        if (authToken == null || !isValidToken(authToken.get(0))) {
            final ServerResponse serverResponse = new ServerResponse();
            serverResponse.setStatus(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED.getStatusCode());
            return serverResponse;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public boolean accept(final Class declaring, final Method method) {
        // return declaring.isAnnotationPresent(SecurityChecked.class);
        return method.isAnnotationPresent(SecurityChecked.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcess(final ServerResponse response) {
        final String header = servletRequest.getHeader(AUTH_TOKEN);
        LOGGER.info("post-processing response " + header);
        final String authToken = TokenUtils.createToken(PATTERN.split(header)[1]);
    }
}
```

and in logs I see

```
(http--0.0.0.0-9090-1) post-processing response InvalidTokenValue:user:1377552546572
```